How do I fix this hole beneath my tile floor?
I need to replace one broken tile in my kitchen floor. Never done tile work before but plan on using this tutorial.
However, when I start to pull up the broken bits there’s a pretty deep hole in the concrete.


Is this serious? Do I need to fix it before replacing the tile?

Please don't expect us here to watch a 13 minute video to help you figure out a problem.  Just state the issue.   Yes you need to fill in the hole in the concrete, but the supplied pic make it difficult to determine the depth.  (how deep is "pretty deep" )  The same thin set you will set ther tile with may be able to be used.  Please supply a better pic with the debris out and an indication of depth.
